# How do I make my custom table control empty after saving records in Maximo

Tags: javascript, customization, maximo

[timesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75D9U.jpg)

I have Maximo 7.6.1.2,
There is a custom table control containing some data and I want to make it empty after saving records ?
as it appear without any record.

Thanks

There is a property "Start Empty=true" so when the application is launched the table control shows empty.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The custom table control has a Relationship property. If you set the where clause for that relationship to something false, like `3 = 4`, then the relationship will not find data, but you will still be able to add rows. On save, data will be re-fetched from the database using the relationship's where clause, which will not find the data you just saved, making the table be empty again.